# Change id value on external page after win.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to js and have been forcing myself to do most of my front end work with it as I feel it is the best learning experience for me at my job.

In a nutshell, I am trying to take the current page url and paste it into the 'title' text-area on the new page.

Basic idea: Open new tab after clicking a button.

```
var curUrl = window.location.href;
var link   = 'www.issue.com/'
var button = $('#my-button');

button.on('click', function() {
  window.open(link, '_blank');
});
```

After it opens the desired site, I'd like to paste the url from the previous site inside of the new sites input.

```
$(document).on('load', function() {
  $('#title-box').val(url);
});
```

I have spent a few hours trying multiple things that I have found in my time researching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you reload a page, you have to reload all the javascript as well. If you want to transfer information from one page to another, there are a couple of options: 1. embed the information in the url (e.g. www.example.com/page.html?additional-info); 2. use a session or cookie variable; 3. use server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can get URL using JS by;

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Now there are two ways to achieve what you want;

**1. Store data in local storage/ session storage**

```
  localStorage.setItem("prevurl", url); //OR sessionStorage.setItem("prevurl", url);
```

Now proceed as per your code in newly opened page;

```
$(document).on('load', function() {
    var prevUrl = localStorage.getItem("prevurl"); //OR sessionStorage.getItem("prevurl");
    $('#title-box').val(prevUrl);
});
```

**2. Second option is like below, i.e., send previous url via get parameter**

In previous page;

```
 $("button").click(function(){
    window.open("newpageurl?ref=" + window.location.href);
 })
```

In new page;

```
  var curUrl = window.location.href;
  var ref = getRefFromUrl(curUrl);   //implement getRefFromUrl function yourself
```

And finally;

```
  $('#title-box').val(ref);
```

Comment: I am trying to do it the first way as I feel like my team will understand that more. I can tell that it is storing the sessionStorage info but it is not changing the
 $('#title-box).val(ref);
I have since tried to test it with the alert(prevUrl); but nothing is happening.

Comment: var url     = window.location.href;
    var issues  = 'www.issues/create'
    var button  = $('#ticket');
    
    button.on('click', function() {
      sessionStorage.setItem("prevurl", url);
      window.open(issues,'_self');
    });
    
    $(document).on('load', function() {
      var prevUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('prevurl');
      window.setTimeout( show_popup, 1000 );
      alert(prevUrl);
    });

This is my current code.

Comment: Any error in browser console? And also you should try localStorage, sessionStorage works only if you redirect to another page but on same tab or window.

Comment: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT 
I am redirecting within the same window but opening a new tab for convenience to our end user.

Comment: Can you please try localStorage instead of sessionStorage?

Comment: $(document).on('load', function() {
  var prevUrl = localStorage.getItem('prevurl');
  alert(prevUrl);
});

Comment: In case you are fetching data from localStorage, you have to set data in localStorage too in previous page instead of sessionStorage.

Comment: button.on('click', function() {
  localStorage.setItem("prevurl", url);
  window.open(issues,'_self');
});

$(document).on('load', function() {
  var prevUrl = localStorage.getItem('prevurl');
  alert(prevUrl);
});

Comment: Does the fact that the page I am opening is external cause any issues?

Comment: Yes, probably so, if it is from another domain then localStorage will not work.